# How do I connect a pendrive using an OTG cable on my phone?

Tags: 8.1

I know that it was not supported in previous version.

Does Windows Phone 8.1 support it now?

Or is there any talk about releasing such update in future...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows Phone 8.1 [does not support USB OTG yet](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-US/OEM/docs/Driver_Components/USB).

[Windows 10 Mobile will support USB OTG](http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-phone-supports-usb-mass-storage-peripherals), but I'm not sure if that requires new hardware. From my own tests the current Insider Preview Build 10149 does not yet include this feature.