# Does the Lumia 435 support USB OTG?

Tags: 8.1, usb, lumia-435

I am seeing conflicting evidence online. On the one hand, some forum posts claim that it is not supported *yet*. However, these are from March-July 2015. An example from this same forum: [How do I connect a pendrive using an OTG cable on my phone?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9888/how-do-i-connect-a-pendrive-using-an-otg-cable-on-my-phone)

On the other hand, some claim that Microsoft wanted to implement this or implemented it for Windows 8.x.

My Lumia 435 is running Windows 8.1. Would USB OTG work on my phone?

Answer (score 2):

No in windows 8.1 It is not supported - the OTG depends on the processor used and not only on the OS.Only if you find it the the specs given by the Microsoft says OTG supported, then YES. But [Lumia 435](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/mobile/phone/lumia435-dual-sim/specifications/) is not.